# Change size of showCamera overlay

Tags: ios, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I am trying to add additional interface elements to a showCamera display in my iOS app.

I know I can add an overlay with the code below. The problem: This overlay will **always** have the size of the entire screen. This is a problem as the camera's default control elements (flash, HDR, camera switcher) are not accessible anymore.

Setting `touchEnabled: false` in `createView()` makes it so that all events are passed through. This makes the original control elements work, at the expense of my new elements not being accessible at all.

So my idea was to make the view smaller so that it would not obstruct the original elements at the top. My own controls would be positioned on the middle/right, so no conflict there. However, no such luck.

Setting `height`/`width` attributes in `createView` does nothing. Setting these properties later on (either directly or through `animate()` has no effect.

My simplified code:

```
var myOverlay = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#0F0', // just to see what is happening
    height: 200 // does not work
    // touchEnabled: false
    // touchEnabled apparently can't be re-enabled for objects contained within this view.
});

var mySlider = Titanium.UI.createSlider({
    [...]
});
myOverlay.add(mySlider);

Titanium.Media.showCamera({
    overlay: myOverlay,
    [...]
});

myOverlay.height = 200; // does not work
myOverlay.animate({height: 200}); // does not work
```

All these methods to control the height do work when I add the same overlay to a Window or another overlay. Not so when I use `showCamera()`.

**Question**: How do I control the size of the `myOverlay` or how do I otherwise make the standard control elements accessible while also letting me throw in my own controls?

Answer (score 0):

If you `myOverlay` doesn't actually need to cover those controls then you could try to set the `opactity` to a value below `1` and keep the `touchEnabled` set to `false` as to pass through the events. I assume this way the user could still see the controls through the the `myOverlay`. Also have you tried messing around with the positioning: `top, right, bottom, left`?

This may be a terrible workaround but if the first view is the full size then you could also try to set the `opacity` to `0` and then add another view inside of the first view with your proper size and slider in it?

Comment: The opacity doesn't impact this at all. Even if the view is invisible it keeps me from getting at the controls behind it.

Comment: Adding another view inside won't help either, I'm afraid. If I set the parent element to be `touchEnabled:false`, then this also goes for all child elements, with no way (I know of) to change this.

Comment: I know that the Child elements get `touchEnabled` property from the parent but you can override it per Child. However after taking a better look at the KitchenSink it seems the Camera Overlay they provide does indeed cover the default camera controls.

Comment: Unless I am doing something wrong, you can't change touchEnabled on the child elements. Just tried adding another view to the overlay to put my control elements into, with no luck. Changing `top` etc didn't have any effect either, btw. Looks like the overlay's size/position is totally fixed when it comes to `showCamera`. Thanks for your ideas though!

Comment: Hey _Lasar I'm not sure if this will work with the camera but in the newest KS examples https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/master/demos/KitchenSink/Resources/examples/camera_video.js they build their own default camera buttons you need right into the overlay. Hope this truly fixes the issue.